# Jetpack Compose font rendering mismatch with Figma

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, figma, android-fonts

I am developing an android app using Jetpack Compose.

For texts, I use the same fonts and properties that our designers specified in Figma.
But when comparing the rendered result with the Figma layouts pixel by pixel, there is a discrepancy in the letter spacing, although I used exactly the same font, font size and letter spacing (0px) - see the pic attached.

Why is this so? How can I fix this to achieve pixel perfect result? Thanks

[image]